# Public instance of FactoryClass

Tags: excel, vba

I created two classes, one for the object I need (action), and a second as a factory class that I use to keep track of every instance of each class I created through arrays (ACTIONS(), OTHER(), etc()).

Actions are created from a userform and by the factory.

How could I do so that the same factory (I need the arrays) could be used by another userform (first userform is used to create the action, second to sort the ActionFactory actions array)?

I can't manage to share my `ActionFactory` between the two forms, declaring it public returns an error. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Sub question: Whats the best design --> Factory class or factory method in the class itself?

Edit additional info
Here is how I create the Action object from my Userform

```
Option Explicit
Private ActionFactory As New Factory

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim test As Action
    Set test = ActionFactory.CreateAction(Tit.value, ComboBox1.ListIndex, ComboBox2.ListIndex, Startdate.value, EndDate.value, Owner.value)
    test.draw
    Dim act() As Action
    act = ActionFactory.GetTheActionsArray
    Debug.Print UBound(act)
End Sub
```

This is my factory and the Actions array & creator

```
Option Explicit
Private ACTIONS() As Action
Private OTHERS() as Other
Private counter As Integer

Public Function CreateAction(t As String, d As Integer, c As Integer, std As String, edt As String, ownr As String) As Object
    counter = Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Cells(1, 1).value
    ReDim Preserve ACTIONS(counter)
    With New Action
        .SetTitle = t
        .SetDepartement = d
        .SetCategory = c
        .SetStartdate = std
        .SetEndDate = edt
        .SetOwner = ownr
        .SetIndexValue = counter
        Set ACTIONS(counter) = .Self
        Set CreateAction = .Self
    End With
    Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Cells(1, 1).value = Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Cells(1, 1).value + 1
End Function
```

The code works, What I can't manage to do is to retrieve the values stored in ACTIONS() of ActionFactory on another userform that userform1.

This also lead me to another question I have. 
How to get rid of that counter on the Factory class. 
I would prefer something in the lines of :

```
If ACTIONS() =  null Then
    ReDim ACTIONS(0) 
Else
    ReDim preserve ACTIONS(ubound(ACTIONS) + 1)
end if
```

obviously, this does not work.
BR,
Bob

Comment: I feel there might just be a misunderstanding or a wrong word here. What you describe is not so much a factory but more of a collection class `Actions` which has the sole purpose of tracking/managing instances of the `Action` class. Can you agree with this @RobRkt? There could surely be an additional class `ActionFactory`, that, depending on the circumstances, could be stand-alone or integrated into `Actions`.

Comment: Also could you share some more details regarding the forms: What connects them? There has to be some code that will provide the forms with data and have them show up. Where are you declaring your `ActionFactory` public and what error happens?

Comment: It does both, factory and collection. It can create & store multiple class I created. The term factory may be wrong but it does create the action, however the main role in our situation is the collection role.